# WCF Call during Service OnShutDown()

Tags: c#, wcf

I know there are a few other similar questions on this topic, but none of them seem to have an answer so I thought we could all hash it out here.

I have a WCF service running on my servers, and I am attempting to send a status message when the server is shut down by overriding "OnShutDown()".

This can be seen as follows:

```
     protected override void OnShutdown()
           {
               try
               {
                   client.updateInvStatus(machineName, "Client Host Has Shutdown");
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   EH.writeToErrorLog("||OnShutdown||Error Shutting Down System \r\n" + ex);

               }
               base.OnShutdown();
           }
```

This seems to work about 50% of the time, the other 50% I get the following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure         channel for SSL/TLS with authority '"ENDPOINT ADDRESS REMOVED'. --->     System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitF orReply(TimeSpan timeout)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebExceptoon webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Ascertain.AscertainAgent.IService.updateInvStatus(String hostNM, String invValue)
   at Ascertain.AscertainAgent.ServiceClient.updateInvStatus(String hostNM, String invValue) in C:\Users\daladd\Documents\CS\Ascertain\Ascertain\Ascertain\Service References\AscertainAgent\Reference.cs:line 209
   at Ascertain.Service1.OnShutdown() in       "FILE LOCATION REMOVED"\Service1.cs:line224
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this would occur?

Comment: Just a guess, but race condition? The server is shutting down faster than it can send out the message to tell everybody that it's shut down? Perhaps a delay after sending out your final message might help?

Comment: I am messed around a bit with having the service request more time before shutdown but Microsoft has limited this ability significantly since Vista. This could absolutely be the issue but I would think that it would fail 100% of the time in that case.

Comment: not necessarily, that's why it's called a race condition.

Comment: So when you are sending this message, is the connection supposedly already established? The built-in WCF transport channels, such as TcpTransport, will silently close connections after a period of inactivity (default is 2 minutes), and then will re-establish the connection when another message is sent. If that's what is happening in your case, then you could increase the idle timeout and/or periodically send a simple message to keep the connection alive. Based on the error, looks like it might be unable to re-establish the connection during shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up following what Dr.Wily had to say. I added a keep alive to my connection and now the code will work every time. Basically windows won't open any new connections during the OnShutDown() method, so if the connection has timed out it wont work properly.

If anyone has an idea around this that would still be amazing because with this method I will have 2000 persistent connections to my central server. Shiraz, I did try changing the registry key to allow for a longer timeout, but time didn't end up being an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the time out of the shutdown. If the shutdown takes too long the process gets killed. This could be happening to you.

Try increasing the timeout here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\WaitToKillServiceTimeout

There may be an event in the event log saying that the process was killed.